# Attempting to webscrape data but my for/in loop (using python) will not iterate through...why does it not iterate?

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler

My for/in loop doesn't seem to request the html page of each url. Instead, my loop only chooses the last url to go get.

I've looked around on the internet and am using a for/in loop that people have suggested will work but for some reason it does not and I don't know what the fix is.

```py
# Beautiful Soup Functions
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#url's to goto
base_url = 'https://www.espn.com/soccer/league/_/name/'
url_list = ['esp.1','ita.1','eng.1']

#url loop   
for url in url_list:
    print(base_url+url)
    r = requests.get(base_url+url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
print(soup.title.string)

#loop through standings table and pull data
```

expected results is that the for/in loop would go to each url and pull back the html code and then I could execute my other code (loop through standings) to pull back the table on each html page. However, the for/in loop does not iterate. It is only pulling back the html page for the last concatenated item, thus, eng.1.  What I really don't understand is why the print (base_url+url) will print out all 3 concatenated urls; however, the print(soup.title.string) only indicates one url has been requested?

Comment: Your `print(soup.title.string)` happens after the for loop finishes. The variable `soup` gets overwritten every time you get a new url. You need to create an empty list _before_ the for loop and `empty_list.append(soup)` inside the for loop. Then you can work with all the results outside of the for loop as they will be contained in the list.

Comment: In python, indentation matters. You're not doing `print` until *after* the loop has run its course, so you're only seeing the *last* value from `soup.title.string`. Indent that line so it's consistent with the lines above it.

Answer (score 0):

See below (working code)

```
# Beautiful Soup Functions
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#url's to goto
base_url = 'https://www.espn.com/soccer/league/_/name/'
url_list = ['esp.1','ita.1','eng.1']

data = {}
for url in url_list:
    print(base_url+url)
    r = requests.get(base_url+url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
    print(soup.title.string)
    data[base_url+url] = soup

# now you can work with 'data'
```

output

```
https://www.espn.com/soccer/league/_/name/esp.1
Spanish Primera División News, Stats, Scores  - ESPN
https://www.espn.com/soccer/league/_/name/ita.1
Italian Serie A News, Stats, Scores  - ESPN
https://www.espn.com/soccer/league/_/name/eng.1
English Premier League News, Stats, Scores  - ESPN
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create empty list and can add what you want in for loop

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#url's to goto
base_url = 'https://www.espn.com/soccer/league/_/name/'
url_list = ['esp.1','ita.1','eng.1']
titles=[]
html_sources = []
#url loop
for url in url_list:
    print(base_url+url)
    r = requests.get(base_url+url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
    titles.append(soup.title.string)
    html_sources.append(soup)
print (titles) #return titles of all 3 sites as a list
print (html_sources)#return html_sources of all 3 sites as a list
```